# SCCM deploys Defender updates but not Office 2016 updates

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, sccm-2012-r2

I'm just pulling my hairs out at this SCCM issue, it seems to push out Windows Defender updates just fine but not Office 2016 Pro Plus (not O365) updates.
I've checked that our boundary group is set, the ADR is on, the updates are being downloaded and even listed in software updates in SCCM, they just aren't pushing out to clients. Test members are in the collection specified for the ADR as well.

Even if I run the rule now, nothing happens really...

We only have one SCCM server that also runs WSUS and about 400 PCs that need Office updates. Windows Updates seem to be deploying ok but then again I haven't had time to check those, but Defender updates appear almost every day...

Both the software available time and installation deadline are set to as soon as possible on the ADR. When I go into Software Center on an affected machine, Defender updates show up but Office updates don't at all...

Any thoughts?

This is SCCM 1902 on Server 2012 R2. Clients are all Windows 10.

Comment: Our Default-Site-Boundary-Group has a member count of zero but a site system count of 1. We have a second Boundary Group that was created by someone else here before me which does have 1 member count. Could this be why updates aren't pushing out? I know that in the ADR deployment settings it says download and install software updates from the distribution points in site default boundary group. I just can't figure out which of the two groups we have is the default one, where does one check that setting from?

Comment: What do the logs on the clients tell you?

Comment: Not much except for:
<![LOG[EnumerateUpdates for action (UpdateActionInstall) - Total actionable updates = 1]LOG]!><time="10:09:06.225-60" date="05-15-2019" component="UpdatesDeploymentAgent" context="" type="1" thread="968" file="updatesmanager.cpp:1881">

All the time...

Almost as if it only keeps detecting one update which is probably the windows defender one...